# Chain commands until variable is not empty or undefined?

Tags: bash, shell, command, variable-assignment, chain

I'm trying to populate a variable with an executable to be called later. I know the following is wrong because it's testing return values, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly (wrapped added for easy viewing):

```
CHECKSEC=`which checksec 2>/dev/null` || `which checksec.sh 2>/dev/null` || 
  `ls /usr/local/bin/checksec 2>/dev/null` || `ls /usr/local/bin/checksec.sh 2>/dev/null`
```

More correctly, I know I can do it with a bunch of `if` statements, but I'm trying to avoid it because it unrolls into about 4 or 8 blocks:

```
if [ -z "$CHECKSEC" ]; then
  CHECKSEC=`which checksec 2>/dev/null`
fi
...

if [ -z "$CHECKSEC" ]; then
  echo "Unable to locate checksec. If you have it, be sure its on PATH. If"
  echo "  you need it, you can download it from http://www.trapkit.de/tools/."
  exit 1;
fi
```

Is it possible to chain commands to populate a variable like I'm trying to do? (Or is this one of those "why would you do that"?)

If so, how do I chain the commands so that [particular] processing stops when a variable is not empty and not undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brute force way to do what you seem to be trying to do is:

```
CHECKSEC=$(which checksec 2>/dev/null ||
           which checksec.sh 2>/dev/null || 
           ls /usr/local/bin/checksec 2>/dev/null ||
           ls /usr/local/bin/checksec.sh 2>/dev/null
          )
```

It isn't particularly elegant, but it should do the job.  Using `$(…)` in place of backticks (`` `…` ``) is generally a good idea.  It is tempting to use:

```
CHECKSEC=$( {which checksec || which checksec.sh || 
           ls /usr/local/bin/checksec || ls /usr/local/bin/checksec.sh; } 2>/dev/null)
```

to reduce the number of redirections.  It's also tempting to consider:

```
CHECKSEC=$( { PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; which checksec || which checksec.sh; } 2>/dev/null)
```

so that `which` will look in `/usr/local/bin` as a last resort.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. The last one was most compact and it tested well for the negative cases.

Comment: Strictly, the last version is not quite the same as the `ls` versions; it won't list a script in `/usr/local/bin` if it is not executable whereas the `ls` variant will.  My suspicion is "that's OK", but you need to be aware of the difference.  (I only noticed that just now.)

Comment: *"My suspicion is "that's OK"... "* - yep, that was a bug and I did not realize was lying in wait. Thanks again.

Comment: You made that look embarrassingly easy. I think it puts the question somewhere around "enthusiast programmer who does not know how to turn on the computer." What should I have searched for? I picked obvious terms like those used in the tags. I got back single variable/single command hits; and I did not get back the elegant one-liners.

Comment: Sometimes, there's no substitute for many years of experience. If it's any consolation, my first thoughts were in the direction of `for dir in …` which looked OK until I realized you were looking for `checksec` or `checksec.sh`, which could be handled by nested loops (one on directories, one on the two script names), but then you're using `which` to look down PATH and `ls`, so that didn't seem so good, but nested loops on command and name — `for cmd in which ls; do for name in checksec checksec.sh; do CHECKSEC=$( $cmd $name 2>/dev/null ); [ -n "$CHECKSEC" ] && break; done; done` — could work.

Comment: IOW: there's more than one way to do it.  I'm not sure what the best way to search for it would be.

Answer (score 1):

This looks for "not_this", "ls" and "nor_that" in $PATH and /usr/local/bin.

"ls" should be found.

```
#!/bin/bash

locate_cmd()
{
   which "$1" || ls /usr/local/bin/"$1" 2>/dev/null
}

c=`locate_cmd not_this` || c=`locate_cmd ls` || c=`locate_cmd nor_that` || echo nope

echo cmd=$c
```

Comment: @Hans - this is kind of clever (or clever to me because I did not think about it). I liked Jonathan's answer because it was an elegant one-liner. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I like Jonathan's way, too. I often think about functions first because they can easily be extended, but I like the elegance and simplicity of his approach.